# How do I reach an object in a parent module from a class in a child module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two relevant files. A `/main.py` and a `/a/b.py`.
`/main.py` imports `/a/b.py`:

```py
...
bot = interactions.Client() # the object I want in b.py

importlib.import_module("a.b")
...
```

`/a/b.py:`

```py
class Command:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "foo"

    @bot.decorator() # bot is undefined currently
    def dec_func(self, args):
        # do things
```

---

I've tried...

- using pickle to store the `bot` object in a file and loading it in `b.py`, but I'm not sure that's a viable solution just yet. I might have to use dill since pickle gave me a `weakref` error
- wrapping the `Command()` in another `Parent` class and having `Parent` receive the `bot` object in `__init__()` so that it's accessible to the child class

```py
class Parent:
    global bot
    def __init__(self, bot: interactions.Client):
       self.bot = bot

    class Command:
       @bot  # returns: undefined
       ...
```

- Adding `from main import bot` in `b.py`, but that won't work since that will duplicate the event loop already running that `main.py` started (unless I can add an `if __name__ == "__main__"` check?)
- Wrapping my `main.py` in a function, doing an `__name__ == "__main__"` check, importing `main` from `b.py`, but then I think I'm deep inside an instance maze, as that returns `bot is not defined`

How do I access `bot`?

Comment: similar here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622237/how-to-access-objects-from-another-module , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168024/python-access-objects-from-another-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, apparently it sufficed to move `bot = interactions.Client` to a separate `bot.py` and have both my modules and `main.py` import `bot.bot` when needed

`main.py`

```py
from bot import bot
from a import b

# do things with b

bot.start()
```

`a/b.py`

```py
from bot import bot

@bot.decorator
async def foo():
    ....
```

`bot.py`

```py
bot = interactions.Client()
```

And that works